# Why is configure so slow in MSYS?

Tags: msys

When I use MSYS to compile something, the `./configure` step can take longer than the `make`.  However, the same process in Linux has a fast configure and slow make.  Is this just some setting in MSYS that is bogging down my system?  Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Typical `configure` scripts do a *lot* of starting small subprocesses. On Unix-like operating systems, this is done with the `fork()` and `exec()` function calls, which have very particular semantics that need to be preserved (for example, copy-on-write shared memory after forking). On Windows, subprocesses are created with `CreateProcess()` which has very different semantics (eg. completely separate memory space from the parent). In order to execute Unix-like scripts and programs correctly, MSYS needs to do a lot of emulation work to make creating new processes on Windows work like `fork()/exec()` on Unix. This ends up being slower than an OS that offers those function calls natively.

Comment: It's actually not that bad to `CreateProcess` on windows. I think cygwin tries to emulate fork on windows which makes it insanely slow. If bash was not using fork (my guess that it uses fork, but I didn't check) to start processes then configure would run just as fast. On my i7 box when I was trying to fix this "problem" it appeared that cygwin can fork only a few times per second. A way to test speed of fork: while (true); do date; done | uniq -c

Comment: +1 Pavel .. uclinux had the same issue it can run without an MMU and anything with fork used a very slow full copy

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to turn off any virus scanners you have running. They will re-scan an executable every time it is loaded, which absolutely kills script performance.

Even if you don't have anti-virus running, don't forget about Windows Defender. (You may also want to disable User Account Control, though I don't know what impact that has on program load time.)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of disk access is involved, which IMHO slows things down a lot.
For example configure creates temporary source code to be compiled as part of the tests it performs. This creates an object file that has to be deleted again.
What I do to speed up configure is extract the source I want to build on a RAM drive and configure and compile it there.
I recommend using ImDisk (http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) which is free.