# cmake problems in Windows

Tags: windows, gcc, configuration, cmake

I am trying to compile this (*quite complex*) piece of code with cmake and MinGW in Windows:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the `CMakeLists.txt` file (which works correctly in Linux):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER path/to/gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER path/to/g++)

project(cmake_test)

add_executable(a.exe test.cpp)
```

With the command:

```
cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles" .
```

I get these errors:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeMinGWFindMake.cmake:20 (MESSAGE):
  sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:

  C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/sh.exe

  For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.

  Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.

  If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)


CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/cmake_test/CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/cmake_test/CMakeFiles/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

These errors did not help me much. Considering it works in Linux, it must be something related to the Window's configuration.

Thank you for any help!

Configuration:
 - Windows 7
 - MinGW/GCC 4.6.1

Comment: The error message from CMake is clear: Make sure you don't have sh in your path. That is: Don't run CMake -G"MinGW Makefiles" from your MSys prompt.

Comment: So why having sh.exe in my path is a problem?

Comment: By running `where sh.exe` i found it at `C:\Cygwin64\bin\sh.exe` and `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH`bin`sh.exe`. How should i remove `Cygwin` and `OpenSSH ` main folders without breaking them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to you have in your path  `C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/`, for generating  projects with CMake and MinGW, delete it from your path and add `C:/MinGW/bin/` instead

Comment: What about `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\msys2`. Is this totally unrelated?

Answer (score 5):

You may have better results with `-G "MSYS Makefiles"` instead of `"MinGW Makefiles"` - but I warn you - [it is going to be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256214/why-is-configure-so-slow-in-msys).

Answer (score 2):

Removing sh.exe from the PATH improved thing.
I get more errors, but at a later stage...