# MinGW sh.exe must NOT be in your path

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, clion

Currently trying to setup my C development environment on windows with MinGW and it looks like CMAKE is giving me the following error:

```
sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:
C:/Program Files/Git/user/bin/sh.exe
For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.
Run cmake from a shill that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.
If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles
```

That error is being thrown inside of CLion IDE. I am not sure if I need to change settings inside of CLion or what. I have looked at my windows path and I do not see any reference to sh.exe.

My path is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin;C:\Users\wesle\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

Comment: check for `C:/Program Files/Git/user/bin` in your path. You have GIT installed alongside with its shell.

Comment: Remove it from your `PATH` then?

Comment: As stated I have already looked in my `PATH` and I do not see any references to /Git/ or sh.exe

Comment: @Septimus where are you getting the value of `PATH` from? I'll take a guess that what you've posted is the *system* `PATH` variable, and that you also have a user `PATH` that contains `C:/Program Files/Git/user/bin`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake problems in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047693/cmake-problems-in-windows)

Answer (score 77):

For me, this simple parameter passed to cmake has worked `-DCMAKE_SH="CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND"`.

Comment: if you're using CLion, what @Elia means is, that you should go to `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake` and where it says CMake options paste `-DCMAKE_SH="CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND"`

Answer (score 7):

Check you really do not have `sh.exe` in your `PATH` by opening a *Windows Command Line* and typing `where sh.exe`. If you have this file in your path, the command will return its path (then you should remove it from your `PATH`) else if windows return it was not found, try to clean up the folder `CMakeFiles` and a file name `CMakeCache.txt` somewhere inside your project folder.

Comment: that was useful, ty.

Answer (score 6):

Just add

> `set(DCMAKE_SH="CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND")`

to your

> CMakeLists.txt file

Comment: This or the response by @Elia is the correct answer, imho. Asking the user to change their PATH variable, possibly/probably affecting other applications is not ideal (I prefer to edit the CMakeLists file so that I have a reference of the fix for next time).

Answer (score 1):

It's the problem of your git's path.
I assume you are using the Clion, just check if you have added `%gitpath%\bin`to your path, that's where the problem is. You should use `%gitpath%\cmd`instead, typically for me it's `D:\Git\cmd`.Since the former one includes `sh.exe` in your path which results in the error.

Comment: This answer does not add anything new to existing answer, posted between 1 and 2 years ago.

Comment: I seem to have the latter (%gitpath%\cmd).
However, "which sh.exe" returns: "/usr/bin/sh.exe"
I am using gitbash on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I like @Elia's answer, but if you are using CLion, it uses the `CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles` CMake generator which doesn't have the `sh.exe` checking problem.  Add this to your CMake line:

```
-G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly this setup (working from terminal here), but got the same error. In my case, `sh.exe` was **not** in my path, but was built into the terminal I was using (cmder). Switching to regular CMD worked for me.