# CMake project generate on VSTS Windows Host fails due to sh.exe being on Path

Tags: c++, cmake, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm having some issues getting a Cmake project building on a windows container.

Calling a cmake command (specifically: `cmake -G CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles -DCMAKE_SH=CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../`) on a Hosted VS2017 build agent fails due to sh.exe being found on PATH:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeMinGWFindMake.cmake:12 (message):
sh.exe was found in your PATH, here: C:/Program Files/Git/bin/sh.exe
```

A [different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45104058/5272385) stack overflow answer led me to believe that supplying the argument `-DCMAKE_SH=CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND` would suppress this behaviour, but I've had no luck.

Manually removing it from the PATH using:

`setx /M PATH "%PATH:C:/Program Files/Git/bin/sh.exe;=%"`

Doesn't seem to have an effect (or perhaps the cmake build and cmd command share the same cmd session, so the PATH change isn't propagated).

It would seem from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49292594/5272385) answer that I can persist a PATH change using `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]${env:PATH};$newPath";`. Before I commit to this route, am I missing something? Surely CMake builds on Windows VSTS agents can't be failing for everyone.

Comment: I was being silly, a generate step inside my cmake script wasn't called with the CMAKE-NOTFOUND flag